# Use multiple templates with separated viewmodel with RazorEngine

Tags: c#, razor, razorengine

I have created a template.cshtml which includes 2 partials header.cshtml and footer.cshtml.

When it is rendered it looks like this:

[image]

```
IRazorEngineService service = RazorEngine.Engine.Razor;

string _webPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "views");
var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration
{
    //Use this template manager when loading from template files.  
    TemplateManager = new ResolvePathTemplateManager(new[] { _webPath })  
};

service = RazorEngineService.Create(config);
ITemplateKey key = service.GetKey("template");

service.Compile("header", typeof(HeaderViewModel));
service.Compile("footer", typeof(FooterViewModel));

var model = new ContentViewModel();
model.Content = "This is the content";

model.FooterViewModel = new FooterViewModel();
model.HeaderViewModel = new HeaderViewModel();
model.FooterViewModel.Footer = "footer";
model.HeaderViewModel.Header = "header";

var html =  service.RunCompile(key, model.GetType(), model);
```

**template.cshtml**

```
@model RazorMachineTest.ContentViewModel

<html>
<body>
       <header>
           @Include("header", @Model.HeaderViewModel, typeof(RazorMachineTest.HeaderViewModel))
       </header>

       <h1>@Model.Content</h1>

       <footer>
          @Include("footer", @Model.FooterViewModel, typeof(RazorMachineTest.FooterViewModel))
       </footer>

</body>  
</html>
```

**header.cshtml**

```
@using RazorEngine
@using RazorMachineTest

<b>I am inside the</b>
<span>@Model.Header</span>
```

**footer.cshtml**

```
@using RazorEngine
@using RazorMachineTest

<b>I am inside the </b>
<span>@Model.Footer</span>
```

What I do not like about the solution is that the viewmodels must be contained into each other.

I would like to have a separation of each viewmodel, one should not know the other. The reason is that the content should not know a general header or footer or should not be the parent of a general header/footer.

Because I want to re-use the template with many different 'Content' viewmodels.

What exactly do I have to change to make this work basing on my existing code?

Note: Don`t get confused if you read RazorMachine namespaces, that was for testing...

Comment: You're already giving the model in the `@include` so just store them elsewhere and not in the model coming in?

Comment: How can I call the include and not pass the same time the model? Do you have me please a sample code?

Comment: You give the model from somewhere else. It doesn't have to be inside the same model you give to the views. Or you can just always push a simple model that encapsulates the three models, this way they can be separate.

Comment: As I said I do not want to encapsulate any model. But it seems so far there is only the possibility to use the @ViewBag.Header like Stewart said.

Comment: You said you don't want them to know of each other, they don't need to but in any case the view does need to. If that's not suitable then ViewBag is most likely the only reasonable choice.

Comment: As I use now the RenderBody with a master layout as I need the middle content to be exchangeable because of having multiple emails with same header/footer but different content. WetherI go the dynamic bag way with the headers/footers or the strongly typed submodels I have to re-think about the problems I might face and the advantages. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the content for the Header/Footer into the Viewbag

```
var viewBag = new DynamicViewBag();
viewBag.AddValue("Footer", "footer");
viewBag.AddValue("Header", "header");                            
var html = service.RunCompile(key, model.GetType(), model, viewBag);
```

Then in the templates you can access the viewbag with @ViewBag.Header

https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/TemplateBasics.html#Supported-syntax

Comment: I would like to stick to my strongly typed approach because later I want to integrate Intellisense.

Comment: Maybe you can extend the TemplateBase<T> to include properties for your models for your header and footer, keeping them strongly typed.Then you can set the model properties once you have run `service.Compile()` which returns the template. https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/TemplateBasics.html#Extending-the-template-Syntax